# How can I click the button with same id?

Tags: google-chrome, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have two buttons with the same id's (everything is identically). If I click it, it choose automaticly the first button, but I need to click the second oder third.

```
@b.link(:id => "commit").click
```

Comment: You still have to differentiate the two buttons like using a class.

Comment: class is also identically. I can not change the browser code. I can whrite only the test for it.

Comment: then use $.each(".class", function(){ $(this).click(); });

Comment: Is it cucumber code? I use Cucumber with watir-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique on the page, you should report this as a bug.

In the meantime, to click the second link with the same `id` try this:

```
@b.a(:id => "commit", :index => 1).click
```

To click the third one:

```
@b.a(:id => "commit", :index => 2).click
```

By the way, you can click the first one with:

```
@b.a(:id => "commit", :index => 0).click
```